# Adding from different table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

What I want to do is adding hasil2+hasil1 with query:

```
SELECT (hasil2+hasil1) FROM Table1,Table2
```

And the result's is:

**false result:**

[image]

But the result should be like this:
0.7015
0.7792
0.5517

I've done following from this post: [How to add different columns from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723637/how-to-add-different-columns-from-different-tables)
But still getting error..

So how the query should I write?

Comment: What is your schema? What query have you tried?

Comment: can you describe table structure and from where hasil1 and 2 are coming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT
    t1.kd, t1.alt, t1.hasil2 + t2.hasil1 AS hasil
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.kd = t2.kd AND t1.alt = t2.alt;
```

Or, if `alt` is not actually a join column then:

```
SELECT
    t1.kd, t1.alt, t1.hasil2 + t2.hasil1 AS hasil
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.kd = t2.kd;
```

### Demo

Comment: BTW, I have answered first without `SUM(` as it was not needed then Tim has edited. Not fair so far ;)

Comment: @Susang I discovered the typo not by poaching your work, but when I was setting up a demo.   I posted before you, and I could say the same thing that you copied my join logic.

Comment: You can say anything that is true. I thought you are so wise and never lie, but why we are in debate ? it should be noticed by `OP` and `OP` noticed you. That's all, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think with the help of simple `join` you can achieve your desired output:

```
SELECT t1.kd, (t1.hasil2+t2.hasil1) AS result
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.kd = t1.kd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try join-

```
SELECT  (t1.hasil2+t2.hasil1) AS result FROM table1 t1  JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.kd = t1.kd
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query instead. Returns kd, alt and sum of hasil1 and hasil2 and groups the order of the result table by kd column.

```
SELECT table1.kd, table1.alt, SUM(table1.hasil2 + table2.hasil1) AS Total 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.alt = table2.alt 
GROUP BY table1.kd
```

You'll have

```
kd | alt | Total
-------------
1  | a1  | 0.7015
2  | a2  | 0.7792
3  | a3  | 0.5517
```

Comment: There is no need for 'SUM'. by the way this will fail due to missing 'table1.alt' in GROUP BY!

Comment: @jmowla, Yes, there may not be need for SUM, But it works and it provides the answer as asked above and it **so does not fail** . I ran the query and it works. Make sure you check it before you say it will FAIL.

Comment: That's really good to know MySQL is so lenient! I expected to see both individual columns in GROUP BY as SUM is an aggregate function. and you are correct it runs on MySQL regarding to missing column in GROUP BY, but it fails on other databases like PostgreSQL http://rextester.com/MGSE32337 or Oracle http://rextester.com/ZFRQ50008

Comment: it's also good to know that statement will fail on MySQL too if 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' is set in 'sql_mode'

Comment: And I think we've basically stopped promoting the use of comma joins